# Update value in a table in Oracle based upon another table's values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables and I wish to update a column in the first table (`invn_sbs`) based upon the results from another table (`invn_sbs_qty`).

The tables and columns are shown below

Table: `invn_sbs`

```
item_sid  sbs_no  active
--------  ------  ------
   12345       6       0
   23456       6       0
```

Table: `invn_sbs_qty`

```
item sid  sbs_no  store_no  qty 
--------  ------  --------  ---
   12345       6         1    5
   23456       6         10
```

What I wish to achieve is to update `active = 1` in `invn_sbs` table
only if `qty <> 0` and `sbs_no = 6` and `store_no = 1` in table `invn_sbs_qty`.

Therefore only item 12345 would be `active = 1` after running the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following :

```
ITEM_SID    SBS_NO  ACTIVE
--------    ------  ------
  12345        6      0
  23456        6      0

update invn_sbs s
   set active = ( select sign(count(1))
                    from invn_sbs_qty q
                   where q.item_sid = s.item_sid
                     and qty <> 0 
                     and sbs_no = 6 
                     and store_no = 1);

-- results will become :
select * from invn_sbs;
ITEM_SID    SBS_NO  ACTIVE
--------    ------  ------
  12345        6      1
  23456        6      0
```

Comment: Many thanks Barbaros. Testing this now and so far looks good.